# Change app name in apple store of an already released/available iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I released an iOS app in the Apple App Store some weeks ago and now want to rename my app (I only want to add a space). I did not find an "edit name" button in iTunes Connect or a solution via google.

Can someone tell me how to rename the app? Is it enough to rename the app in Xcode to get the name to automatically updated with the next Apple approval? Or do I have to release a completely new app with the new title?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You will need to do an update to the app store.  I would leave your targets and executables the same, just change the Bundle Display Name property in your info.plist to the name you want your app to show on the iphone screen.  That should do the trick.

Comment: Will editing Bundle Display Name also change the name that is displayed in the App Store?

Comment: This is the display name on the iPhone Springboard.  You will setup the name you see in iTunes when you upload your app using iTunes Connect.

Comment: Is it also possible to change CFBundleName without breaking updates?

Comment: Here in 2014, this doesn't work.  This only changes the name of your app as viewed on the iOS device.  You will have to change the name that is displayed on the App Store, within iTunes Connect, and only if you have a new app or an update, which has not yet beep approved.  Once approved, you can not change the name, unless you upload new binary.  See @Gonen's link below.

Answer (score 3):

To change the displayed-name of your application as it will show on the **iPhone screen** ("springboard"),
edit your application's **plist**.

To change the displayed-name of your application in **iTunes App-Store**,
edit the details of the last revision you have **uploaded to iTunes** -
see here the answer from [0x7fffffff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/716216/0x7fffffff):
**[change app name in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10386544/1390251)**