# change app name in App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have app called "X". It's already approved in the app store. Now I want it to be called "X Pro" for some reasons. What should I edit in plist or ITC to change this name? I guess I should change bundle_name or bundle_display_name, but will it change app name in the App Store or it will change just name on the device?

Create new app in ITC is not an option coz app is already approved. Thanks!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you have already created the new version in ITC, you can edit your apps name with the following steps:

In iTunes Connect, click your app and you will see versions at the bottom of the page, click "View Details" of your updated version (e.g. 1.1).

Then click "Edit" next to "Metadate and Upoads"

[image]

In the pop-up change the text in the field "App Name"

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's so easy and obvious, shame on my head :) Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to change the app name in your Info.plist (bundle name and bundle display name)!

Comment: If I create an update for only to change the name for one language, will that make the already released version be unavailable for download (until the new version is approved)?

Comment: @Mick MacCallum is there any way to change the name of app with update? means user don't have to download a separate app but with updating app it changes the app name and icon?

Answer (score 42):

Direct quote from Apple's documentation:

> You can change the name of your existing app only when submitting an
>   update of your app binary. If you submit an app name which is already
>   in use within the same geography in which your app is sold, you will
>   be prompted to enter another name.

I just googled it.

Comment: I know that I can do it via update. The question is WHERE I "can change the name of your existing app". I mean what exactly should I edit - which variable?

Comment: Yes, I did, but all topics are about creating new app in ITC or about updating process, but without details. I guess that I should change bundle_name or bundle_display_name in plist.info, but I'm not sure. Of course I can update and just look the result but it might take a week with no profit since review process is to long.

Comment: Hey it really helps me

Answer (score 22):

With the new updation of iTunesConnect Layout You can change the application name for Appstore by following steps.

- Login with you Apple id at iTunesConnect and go in to the app that you want to change Appstore name.
- Find the field at the left side called `App Information` like in the following screenshot:

[image]

- Here you can find the editable filed called `Name?` that you need to change name what you want to use for next and just save it.

> **NOTE:** You can only edit application name for the app store if your app is as an updated version or rejected state. Live app can not be able to change the name if you want to change name you must be create a new version of your live app.

Comment: nice answer but could you help me in my case that I have already submitted one App on ITC but later that will remove from App Store (note: Not Deleted) then I have uploaded same App with new name & new bundle identifier. But now I have deleted old app & make want to make my new app same name which I deleted from App Store. So kindly help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of itunesConnect now it's appstoreConnect

Answer (score 21):

The name of the app as it appears on the app store is entered when submitting a new or updated app binary. The app name is not actually configured inside the app binary itself. Hope that is clear. If you want to change the launcher name as it appears below the icon in iOS, then you can change that in your actual project configuration.

Comment: can i have something like: `AppName by CompanyName` (on appstore) and after installation `AppName` (on mobile. )