# Change app name App Store

Tags: app-store-connect

A person needs the name of my app currently in App Store. Let's take "ABC" as name of my app. I submit an update to change my app name to "ABCD". Will the other person be able to create an app with the name "ABC"?

Thanks guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change app name in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383593/change-app-name-in-app-store)