# Bundle identifier changed after changing application name

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, identifier

a little stuck here,

I changed the name of my application, the bit that will show under the icon on a device, bundle identifier right ? I want to submit an update to my app, but now my bundle identifier is different, and there is no code signing identity profile to select to validate/distribute. How do I go about submitting my app if the identifiers are different?

Really confused

any help would be much appreciated

thanks

Comment: If you change the bundleID it will be release as an new app.

Comment: If you need to change the App Name ->http://stackoverflow.com/a/10386544/1059705

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default your bundle identifier is com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} in your Info.plist (`Bundle identifier` key), if you change PRODUCT_NAME you change also your bundle identifier. You can specify other bundle identifier in Info.plist which you can find in Project Navigator. To change the name of application in Spring Board (under icon) you have to change `Bundle display name` in Info.plist. For more details about Info.plist read apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: what does this mean for re submitting my app? Hard to explain what I mean.. there is no identity to sign with because I changed the name :S

Comment: Check that Bundle Identifier of your app in Xcode matches Bundle Identifier specified in iTunes Connect

Comment: thanks ye, basically my question is I just want to change the display name, but when I have changed it, the identifier has too, how to just change display name ? :S

Comment: Change `Bundle display name` in Info.plist. Also you can localize this name in InfoPlist.strings

Comment: [This might help you on changing Bundle Display name or the app name in ITC](http://science.opposingviews.com/change-iphone-app-name-8117.html)

Comment: hmm its set how I want it, and testing on my device is correct, yet my identifier name is set to the same thing, different to what I had originally when I first uploaded my app

Comment: would changing the identifier back to what I originally had work? then set bundle display name how I want