# Change Application Name

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I have developed an iOS app, and it was already put into Apple Store. Now I want to change the name of my application.

What are the things I need to consider & update in my xcode project if I want to replace the current app in Apple Store with the new named app?

**Update:**

I'd like to not only change name in Apple store but also change the name in project level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to replace your App ? For just changing the Name ? You don't need to do any thing in your Xcode Project or replace your app. Simply follow these Steps and your App Name will be changed.

Take a look at : [change app name in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383593/change-app-name-in-app-store).

**Update :** If you simply want to change the name of your Xcode Project then it's a simple 3 Step Process :

1. Go to Targets in `Xcode`
2. Go to **Build Setting** on your project's Target.
3. Search for **Product Name** under **Packaging**. Change the value of that what you want the new program name is going to be.

Comment: Thanks, but I do need to change the corresponding name in project level. I'd like to not only change it in Apple store but also change the name in project level.

Comment: @NitinGohel: Oh, I didn't see it. It was really hard to understand what OP wants actually from reading the Question. :)

Comment: Where can I find the value of ${PRODUCT_NAME} ? You said under "Packaging", where is it?

Comment: @Mellon : `Target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name`.

Answer (score 0):

you can change "bundle display name" in info.plist to change the app icon name.

To change the name on Appstore there's already a post on stackoverflow: [change app name in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383593/change-app-name-in-app-store)