# Can I change the name of my App in iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, onchange

I want to change one of my app name which is approved in itunes and i don't want to submit new app on app store, just wanted to change the name of it. Suppose my app name is abc and after chaging i want it xyz. Plese share the procedure.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change name of the same app which is live in itunes store ?

Answer (score 5):

> Yes, you can change it if you submit an update.
>
> You have to click on the new version of your app, then you can edit the "Version Information" and change the name.
>
> For More Info Refer this [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383593/change-app-name-in-app-store)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the name of your App once its approved and available on App store.

But yes while posting a new binary/upgrade to your existing Application you can change the name of your App based upon the availability of that name in App store.

Regards
Rajeev