# Does changing the app name in the Apple App Store require me to change bundle ID?

Tags: ios

I want to change my apps name (really just add a description of what the app does). I have read articles about how to do this by creating a new version and while the app is in an editable state just edit the metadata. -[change app name in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383593/change-app-name-in-app-store)

iTunes Connect FAQs states

"How can I edit my app name? 
App names can only be changed when your app is in an editable state. Changing the app name on iTunes Connect will only change the app name on the App Store. If you need to change the app name that displays on a customer’s device, you need to edit this name in the binary of your app and send a binary update."

My question is: If I alter the name am I required to change the bundle ID? Display name? and all of that or can I leave the binary completely the same and just change the name on the store?

Comment: You answered the question yourself in the paragraph from the iTunes Connect FAQ... "` App names can only be changed when your app is in an editable state. Changing the app name on iTunes Connect will only change the app name on the App Store.`" Answer: put the app into an editable state and change it. A lot of your question is also testable: why not **just try it** and see if you can change the name in the app store without changing anything else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [change app name in App Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383593/change-app-name-in-app-store)

Comment: when you submit new version of your app you can change the app name without changing anything while editing meta data. Just change app name field... And SO is the correct place to ask these kind of questions. it is appear to be off-topic. it is also duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to add description of what it does, you probably just want to change the name on AppStore because thus when people download it, it will have the name without description, which is better for little fonts under the icon. Therefore you don't need to change your bundle ID because you do not need to change the name on user's device. So yes you can leave the binary completely the same.

Comment: You can change the name shown on the device (Bundle Display Name) without changing the Bundle ID (usually something like com.yourcompanyname.appname). Bundle ID is the unique ID of your app, if you change that, it's not the same app any more.