# The App Name you entered has already been used. even though I have no apps

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have no apps in iTunes Connect. I just signed in for the first time, and I am creating an app. It gives me the error: The App Name you entered has already been used. I'm at loss because I logged into the account for the first time 20 minutes ago and haven't done anything on it.

Comment: *"The App Name you entered has already been used."* What about this statement qualifies it only for *your* apps?

Comment: @esqew I thought multiple apps could have the same name

Comment: possible duplicate of [change app name in App Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383593/change-app-name-in-app-store)

Comment: i got u @Jacob so u wanna throw me an upvote lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means the app name is being used by another developer. Two apps on the App Store cannot have the same name. Trying using a similar name or adding descriptive words to the app title.

Comment: Is the app name the app name that appears in the app store or on the home screen.

Comment: Appears in the App Store.